# VSCode - how do I turn off java completely?

Tags: visual-studio-code

How do I turn off the Java Language Server completely?  I can't find it anywhere.  I just want it off so it does not do this "importing root project configuration project".

[image: Starting java]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can disable the `Language Support for Java(TM) by Red Hat` extension in VS Code.

It can either be disabled entirely, or just for your current workspace. If you never want to use it, you can uninstall the extension instead.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

There is now a new setting `java.autobuild.enabled` in RedHat's Java extension ([since this PR](https://github.com/redhat-developer/vscode-java/pull/414)). It will  [not stop importing projects](https://github.com/redhat-developer/vscode-java/issues/1689), but once the project is imported, it will not automatically rebuild it.

To force manual rebuilding, use the Command Palette and run `Java: Force Java Compilation`.